# Wordpress Theme Modifications - Style.css Note Updating

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently working on a website. I am using wordpress along with a theme. I'm trying to make modifications to the theme. I'm doing this via a child theme as recommended.

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to make changes in the child's style.css . However, many of these changes do not seem to be going through.

As an example (refer to my website here: coffeedev.com), I'm trying to make the main container's corners rounded. I'm doing this with the 'border-radius' function.

When I do this in the child theme's style.css, the changes do not take place. So I'm trying to understand why the changes aren't taking place.

From research, I believe it is either due to my webhosting (through godaddy) having some kind of server caching, thus the changes aren't updating when I reload the page, or it is due to some underlying overriding taking place. However, I'm not familiar enough with CSS to determine where the overriding would take place.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you can use chrome and inspect element to see what styles are currently applied and what is not applied. google specificity, its not difficult but long enough to explain. if you make a rule and see no mention of it try viewing the page source and view your css file through the browser

Comment: You probably tried this already, but just in case: Use ctrl+f5 to reload the page and reload any data cached by your browser for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Issues when the server is running ATS, Varnish or similar cache utility that the author has no control over. Sometimes cache files stick around for a while and users have no control over caching applications. If you want your css, javascript, image or other asset updates to be reflected instantly, this is the perfect solution for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-version-in-query-string-modifier/